# IOS 15.5.6 Any way to turn off vibration for certain apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, notifications

For apps like Twitter, I'd like to only receive its notification and badge and NOT the vibration of it. Had this on my Galaxy Note 20, but struggling to find it on my iPhone 11 Pro.

When I go to Settings > Apps > Notifications > Sounds I only see sounds , not to stop it from vibrating like in many other apps.

Any way to do that built in or Third Party apps?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately you cannot select a sound without a vibration, neither for individual apps nor for all of them

Year 2022 and Apple can't do this... I hate this phone!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the notification style for each app. Go to the Settings app, scroll down until you find the app, tap on it, then tap on Notifications.

When you disable Sounds for this app, you also disable vibrations.

If you only want vibration but no sound, you can put your phone into silent mode with the mechanical switch on the top left. All apps that you have enabled for notification sounds now only vibrate for new notifications.

Unfortunately you cannot select a sound without a vibration, neither for individual apps nor for all of them.

Comment: I still get the vibration even with sound off for the app in notifications.